# Query OUPath with AdminSDK "Invalid Input: INVALID_OU_ID"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

Trying to query all users in the OU "LegacyMail" with the new Admin SDK for Apps Script, but it fails:

[image]

The example at developers.google.com shows that it should look like this:

["orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user)

```
function admsdk() {

  var x = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: "acamedomain.com",
    query: "orgUnitPath:/acamedomain.com/LegacyMail"

  });

  Logger.log(x);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
function admsdk() {

  var x = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    customer: "my_customer",
    query: "orgUnitPath='/LegacyMail'"

  });

  Logger.log(x);

}
```

to explain:

1. customer / my_customer isn't strictly necessary but it ensures you get ALL users, not just users who have a primary domain in acamedomain.com.
2. / is the root OU of your domain. /acamedomain.com is not right unless you've explicitly created an OU called that. OUs are independent of SMTP domains.